# Passing a subset of an array to linux spi driver

Tags: c, linux, spi

I have a problem that I'm having difficulty solving. 
I have a union that contains a buffer with a struct mapping the bits of the buffer. Something along the lines of (it is pragma packed of course):

```
union
uint32 buf[512]
struct
uint8_t pad[256];
uint32_t data[256];
```

the `buf[]` part is intended to be passed to the Linux spi driver as a Receive buffer. The issue I'm having is, depending on my transmits, the size of the padding I receive back is variable, and because of this it isn't straight forward to access using the union.

What i need to do is to be able to pass `buf[]` at a specific index to the spi driver, I.E the Rx buffer begins at `buf[128]` instead of `buf[0]`. This isn't always equal, so i have an equation that tells me where i need the start point to be which is `&(buf[0]+padmax-padsize])` which should result in a value between `buf[0]` and `buf[256]`. However, the issue is the spi driver expects the argument of the transfer buffer to contain a pointer to a buffer, and passing it the straight address isn't giving me what i want.

I have also tried assigning a pointer to the address of the above equation and passing that to the `rxbuffer` part of the `spi` struct and it again doesn't give me what i want.

Is it possible to create an array that is a subset of another array, starting at a specified address of the outer array? I think this may solve my problem but I'm also afraid of the memory implications of that

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely that you're calculating the address in 32-bit units (in units of `buf` elements), not bytes as you expect, based on the arithmetic.

Let's simplify the situation, and say the structure is just

```
#define MAX_PAD  256
#define MAX_DATA 256

struct spi_data {
    uint8_t  pad[MAX_PAD];
    uint32_t data[MAX_DATA];
};
```

and that you want to implement a function similar to

```
size_t spi_recv(int fd, struct spi_data *ref, size_t pad, size_t data)
```

where

- `fd` is the file descriptor to [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from
- `ref` is a pointer to the `struct spi_data` to be used
- `pad` is the number of padding entries filled at the end of the `ref->pad[]` array
- `data` is the number of entries filled at the beginning of the `ref->data[]` array
- the return value is the number of `data` entries received (completely filled)

Consider the following (argument checks for `fd == -1`, `ref == NULL`, `pad > MAX_PAD`, `data > MAX_DATA` omitted for simplicity):

```
size_t spi_recv(int fd, struct spi_data *ref, size_t pad, size_t data)
{
    ssize_t  n;

    n = read(fd, &ref->pad[sizeof ref->pad / sizeof ref->pad[0] - pad],
                 pad * sizeof ref->pad[0] + data * sizeof ref->data[0]);

    if (n == -1) {
        /* Error; errno already set */
        return 0;
    } else
    if (n < 0) {
        /* Should never occur, but let's be paranoid */
        errno = EIO;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (n < pad * sizeof ref->pad[0]) {
        /* Only partial padding received */
        errno = 0;
        return 0;
    } else {
        /* Zero or more data words received */
        errno = 0;
        return (n - pad * sizeof ref->pad[0]) / sizeof ref->data[0];
    }
}
```

The pointer to the last `pad` elements of padding is

```
    &ref->pad[sizeof ref->pad / sizeof ref->pad[0] - pad])
```

which is essentially equivalent to `&(ref->pad[MAX_PAD - pad])`, except that instead of the `MAX_PAD` macro, we use `(sizeof ref->pad)/(sizeof ref->pad[0])` to evaluate the number of members declared for the `ref->pad[]` array. (This only works if `ref->pad` is an array; it does not work if it is a pointer.)

As usual, `read()` takes the number of bytes -- not elements of `ref->pad` or `ref->data` -- as a parameter, so we need to multiply the element counts by their respective element sizes in bytes; thus, the number of bytes in `pad` elements of padding and `data` elements of data is `pad * sizeof ref->pad[0] + data * sizeof ref->data[0]`.

Since the function returns the number of complete data words received, the number of padding bytes must be subtracted from the return value, then divided by the data element type (integer division rounding down), to get the number of complete data words.

I don't think the above interface is optimal, however. I particularly dislike the possibility of the SPI transfer ending with a partial word; the above interface does not let the caller detect such a situation reliably.

If you use spidev, the ioctl() interface would be much better to use. For one, you could use `SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(2)` to read the padding and the data into separate buffers, or even `SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(3)` to write a command, followed by a read to the padding buffer and another to the data buffer. The Linux-Sunxi Wiki page has a pretty simple example of this kind of usage [here](http://linux-sunxi.org/SPIdev), except that it uses single reads instead of reading padding into a separate buffer. However, it should be quite simple to extend the examples to do that.